# Is there any way to stop and restart asyncio event loop running in a daemon thread without killing the actual thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have a daemon thread which runs an asyncio event loop in the background that is used to execute some monitoring tasks. I want to have some disable/enable functionality, meaning stop and restart the event loop without killing the background thread. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```py
class AsyncMonitor(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self, name="AsyncMonitoringService")
        self.daemon = True
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self.enabled = False

    def run(self):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
        self.enabled = True
        self.loop.call_later(1, self.run_monitoring)
        self.loop.run_forever()

    def run_monitoring(self):
        some_async_task_scheduling()        
        self.loop.call_later(1, self.run_monitoring)

    def disable(self):
         self.enabled = False
         self.loop.stop()

    def enable(self):
         self.run()

    def stop(self):
        self.enabled = False
        self.loop.close()
```

Executing the `disable` method always kills the thread and then executing the `enable` method runs the code back in the main thread. Is there any way to achieve this disable/enable functionality without killing the thread?

Alternatively, is there any way for the `enable` method to run my code on a new daemon thread?

I basically need to avoid creating a new `AsyncMonitor` instance whenever I want to re-enable the service.

Comment: Why do you want to fool around with the event loop?  Wouldn't it be just as good to pause and resume the monitoring itself (perhaps with a simple flag) and just leave the event loop alone?  If all the tasks are blocked, the event loop will just there; it wouldn't consume any noticeable amount of resources.

Comment: I was just looking to use the native `loop.stop()` and `loop.start()` functions that I would be using if I was dealing with a main thread. I suppose you are right though in that I won't waste too many resources by keeping it running, thanks!